# How to make ggplot2 bar chart color by magnitude and sort by direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar chart on data that looks as follows:

```
 Difference  Name
-120.007482  gene1
 43.901222   gene2
 66.206057   gene3
-277.303125  gene4
 69.487904   gene5
```

I make a bar plot using ggplot2 with the following code:

```
ggplot(readcount_differences, aes(x=gene, y= differences)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust =1))
```

What I want to do now is color and sort the bar plot in order of magnitude. So the Most positive bar plot goes from dark blue to light blue (on the shortest positive) and the most negative goes from dark red to light red (from most negative to least negative).

I think I can do this with facets but I'm not sure how. Any help would appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: Using the fix:**

Colors go to light...

[image]

Comment: You may have a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581746/small-value-variation-invisible-using-scale-colour-gradient2/20584038#20584038) on how to increase resolution for values close to zero using `scale_color_gradientn` and the `rescale` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the data:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" difference  name
-120.007482  gene1
 43.901222   gene2
 66.206057   gene3
-277.303125  gene4
 69.487904   gene5")
```

Create the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(name, difference), y=difference, fill=difference)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", high="darkblue", midpoint=-50) +
  labs(x="\nGene", y="Difference\n") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5))
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: This is closer, but not quite what i need. I want all the ones with positive difference to have a shade of blue and all the ones with a negative difference to have a shade of red...

Comment: Hm, something is going wrong, I'm now getting an error: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". If I take out the line "  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", high="darkblue", midpoint=-50) +" then it works but doesn't give me the color scheme

Comment: Strange, I don't get that error message. Some questions for clarification: Did you read the data in the same way as I did? And did you change the `fill` to `fill=difference`? Which version of R and ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: Ah, I missed the "fill = difference". Now we're really really close, but it gets to light in the middle. This is why I was thinking of using facets. If it scales lightblue to dark blue on one side and light red to dark red on another, it won't blend in in the middle.

Comment: What you could do is specify a mid-color with `mid="green"`. Another possibility is seperate the data in facets with the positive values in one facet and the negative ones in another. However, with the small dataset you provided it's hard to tell what the best strategy is. Can you give a bigger dataset with `dput`?

Comment: I'm interested in the facets approach. Would you be able to just use the data I provided? Put the negative ones in one facet and the positive ones in another?

Comment: Hey, I figured out the rest from what you had. Thanks for all your help -- I'm marking this solved :-).

Comment: Good to read that you already figured it out. If you want to seperate the values in negative and positive facets, you can create a grouping variable with `df$grp <- ifelse(df$difference<0, "neg", "pos")` and then create facets with `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`.